# How to get a list of all of one type of Virtus attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtus

How to get a list of all of one type?
Like for example, a list of all of the String attributes?
Is there an easy Virtus solution or do I have to roll my own?

```
def my_model
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :a, Integer
  attribute :b, Integer
  attribute :c, String
  attribute :d, String
  attribute :w, Float
  attribute :j, Float
end
```

I would like to essentially do `my_model.something = [:c, :d]`

OR is there any other way to get all of the String attributes in list form?

My ultimate goal is to be able to splat the attributes into various validations based on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `attribute_set` method along with the `primitive` to get the attribute Class and then you need to write your own method:

```rb
def self.get_string_attributes
  attributes = []
  self.attribute_set.each do |attribute|
    attributes << attribute.name if attribute.primitive == String
  end
  attributes
end
```

I get this results with your `MyModel`:

```rb
MyModel.get_string_attributes
=> [:c, :d]
```

O̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶g̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶t̶e̶p̶ ̶f̶u̶r̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶m̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶_̶m̶i̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶:̶

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is the perfect response.  Really wish I could give you infinite votes.  Can I ask,  how good of practice is it to use method missing?  I'm just curious because my other devs are pretty hardcore about the code that goes into the application.  Is it pretty common to use it?

Comment: I use it more as a DRY solution. I suggested it as you want to query for different classes but to be honest, in your specific case, it would be really tricky to use it as you need to make sure that the method name has a ruby class name. And as always, code reviews is the best thing to do when working with other devs as long as you do it together.